# How do I find 'n' max elements of a fibonacci heap?

Tags: data-structures, fibonacci-heap

Max Fibonacci heaps can have one pointer to the max element of the structure. But how do I find 'n' of these? As in, how do I find the next max element after the current one?

One caveat is that I cannot remove elements from the structure as the structure might be queried again, for a different number of max elements. For example, I might be asked for the top 3 elements one time and then be queried about top 5 elements.

Or does this necessitate a remove and reinsert? If that's the case, am I better off storing the max elements in a stack/queue and then reinsert them once we serve the query? Also, wouldn't this alter the structure of the tree?

Comment: can you add elements to the structure? or just query it?

Comment: I can add elements to the structure.